# Generatet eMailaddresses from script

Tags: email, jenkins

We have an environment were the `svn` credentials are Linux usernames, consisting of:
one letter of the firstname and 5 letters of the lastname.
However, we have eMailaddresses of the form `firstname`.`lastname`@company.org. We have a way to tie the credential name to the eMailaddress with a script, however I do not know how to tell jenkins to use this script upon detecting a check in from a new user.

Is there an easy way to run a script to generate a user's emailaddress upon the creation of a new user? Alternatively, calculating the eMailaddress each time the user is supposed to receive a mail would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the small pointers from askmish i came to this:

install email-ext

configure project to have `editable email notification`
edit the presend script to read something like:

```
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType
msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, 'address@real.com' )
```

You might want to do some output aswell, since otherwise only the wrong emailaddresses are displayed.